# CodeIgniter protect admin controller with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, digest-authentication

I need to setup .htaccess rules in order to protect admin controller in CodeIgniter.

In .htaccess already have rules for friendly URLs like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

How to add additional rules to protect all under /admin/ folder (controller) with Digest authentication?

I have tried various combinations but none works correct. Here are some rules which I tried just to get clues what I'm looking for:

```
# set an environtment variable "doauth" if the request starts with "/admin/"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/admin/ doauth=1

AuthType Digest
AuthName "Admin Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /hta/.htdigest

# Here is where we allow/deny
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Require valid-user
Deny from env=doauth
Satisfy any
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for controlling access to your admin controller:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/admin/" doauth

AuthType Digest
AuthName "Admin Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /hta/.htdigest

Require valid-user
Satisfy         any
Order           allow,deny
Allow from      all
Deny from       env=doauth
```